# How to create calendar event that comes with Microsoft Teams link to online meeting

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar, microsoft-graph-teams

Using Microsoft Graph API 1.0, how to create a calendar event that comes with link to Microsoft Teams (online meeting)?

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try [Creating online meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) using Graph API. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions to create the meeting. Please let us know if you face any issues.